# Why is Islam open to different interpretations?

Tags: tafseer

I was asked this question by an atheist:

Why is Islam open to so many different (often contrary) interpretations? For example, there are Sunnis and Shias, Sufis and Salafis, different legal schools, traditionalists, modernists, etc. Why didn't Allah communicate His message in an unambiguous, clear way, such that misunderstanding is not even possible?

Answer (score 0):

All ideas and religions are included in this theme.
After the Prophet of Islam attains prophethood and the people gather around him, they give power and glory to his words and religion, and are even willing to sacrifice their property and lives for him and the religion he has brought. The power seekers are queuing up to take it, but they are not able to guide the people in this direction, and the religious people know this. For this reason, the main owners of religion continue to be in conflict with the power seekers, and history is formed as we see it.
In Islam, Islam was on a certain path as long as the Prophet of Islam was alive, but after his martyrdom, two main groups emerged: first, the Shiites, who believed in the rule of Amir al-Mu'minin Ali on the orders of the Prophet, and second, the Sunnis, who according to the Saqifa Council Abu Bakr was considered the successor of the Prophet.
Certainly, when the roads are separated and we reach a crossroads, only one of these two roads will be right and the other will be wrong.
This battle between the main religious leaders and the power seekers has been repeated throughout history, and after both ways, new two ways appear:
In the path of Shiites, some Imams, grains, Sufis, etc. are created
And in the path of the Sunnis, the Shafi'is, the Malikis, the Salafis, etc.
And that God has expressed His message in such a way that if we look for it with an honest eye and away from prejudice, we will surely find it.
But for the last part of your question, "clear way, such that misunderstanding is not even possible?" So what is the use of intellect and authority then? And what will the reward and torment mean?